# Problema al obtener datos con PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

No se que pasa pero no puedo obtener el las filas deseadas cuando llamo al método.

Es algo muy simple obtener las filas con un limite máximo 2 filas y el índice de comienzo se lo mando cuando llamo a la función.

El problema es que ejecuta el ELSE como queriendo decir que no encontró filas cuando realmente si hay filas

...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
    <?php

     include  "Data/base_datos.php";

    class Post extends Base_datos{


          function __construct(){

            parent::__construct();

        }




        //METODO

        function getData($section){


            $conexion = $this->Conectar()->prepare('SELECT * FROM post LIMIT :section, 2');
            $conexion->execute([':section' => $section]);

            $n = $conexion->rowCount();
            if($n){

                $items = array();
                $res = array();

                while($filas = $conexion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                   
                    $item = array(

                        "id" => $filas["Id"],
                        "titulo"=> $filas["Titulo"],
                        "texto"=>$filas["Texto"]

                    );

                    array_push($items,$item);

                }
                //section es el indice del comienzo 
                //n me devulve la cantidad de elementos de mi consulta 

                array_push($res,array("response"=>200));
                array_push($res,$items);
                array_push($res, array("pages"=>($section+$n)));

               
                return $res;



            }else{

                echo "Ya no hay mas datos";

            }


        }


    }



    $caja = new Post();
    $caja->getData(1);
    
?>
```

Comment: El problema es que ejecuta el ELSE como queriendo decir que no encontró filas cuando realmente si hay filas.

Comment: ese comentario agrégalo a la pregunta directamente (editándola) y borra el comentario. Cual es el valor de `$n` al ejecutar?

Comment: ese es el problema toma a $n como un valor vacío por que siempre se ejecuta el else y $n debe tener el valor de las filas devueltas por la consulta .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Hay un problema fundamental en tu sentencia preparada **la ligazón de parámetros** puede no funcionar para algunas clausulas como **LIMIT** (no me preguntes por qué pues lo ignoro.) En [(The only proper) PDO tutorial - Binding Methods](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#methods) encontramos la siguiente observación:

> However, sometimes it's better to set the data type explicitly. Possible cases are:
>
> - LIMIT clause (or any other SQL clause that just cannot accept a string operand) if emulation mode is turned ON.
> - complex queries with non-trivial query plan that can be affected by a wrong operand type
> - peculiar column types, like BIGINT or BOOLEAN that require an operand of exact type to be bound (note that in order to bind a BIGINT value with PDO::PARAM_INT you need a mysqlnd-based installation).
>
> In such a case explicit binding have to be used, for which you have a choice of two functions, bindValue() and bindParam(). The former one has to be preferred, because, unlike bindParam() it has no side effects to deal with.

En consecuencia tu solución es ligar explícitamente el valor que estas pasando al *marcador posicional* **:section** así:

```
<?php
// Preparar el query con LIMIT establecido explícitamente
// le puse un default 1 si el valor no es numérico como seudocontrol de entrada del parámetro.
$limitclause = is_numeric($section) ? "LIMIT $section, 2" : 'LIMIT 1, 2';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post '.$limitclause;
// Ejecución normal del query
$conexion = $this->Conectar()->prepare($query);
$conexion->execute();
```

Vi que en tus anotaciones en la pregunta resaltas que no falla cuando se hace explícito el paso de parámetros.
Decidí responder porque me parece importante mostrar y destacar que en el caso de LIMIT no es conveniente manejarlo como tratabas de hacerlo, ofreciendo una referencia adecuada.

Comment: gracias amigo me funciono pero no entiendo por que presenta ese problema cuando he trabajado de la misma forma anteriormente en otra ocasión.

Comment: @YOSIPMIKE. Al parecer tiene que ver con **"if emulation mode is turned ON."** y el asunto es que ese modo de emulación se debe manejar con cuidado. Yo todavía no tengo suficientemente claras la implicaciones de habilitarlo/deshabilitarlo y simplemente no lo toco y dejo las opciones por defecto y para casos como el de LIMIT uso el paso explícito de los parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás poniendo la sección como inicio de resultados y, seguramente, tienes menos registros que los indicados por ID de sección. Suponiendo que `$section` tiene un valor de 5, estás pidiendo que la consulta inicia desde la posición 5 y devuelva 2 filas (es decir, el 5 y el 6).

```
SELECT * FROM post LIMIT :section, 2
```

Entonces, debes filtar por sección:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE section = :section
```

Tienes dos opciones para limitar la cantidad de resultados:

**1. Con contador inicial y total de filas**

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE section = :section LIMIT 0, 2
```

**2. Sin contador inicial, solo con total de filas**

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE section = :section LIMIT 2
```

Ambas van a funcionar de la misma forma y depende de tus preferencias cual usar. Yo me inclino por la segunda y reservo la primera para paginación.

Comment: No funciono amigo, Yo pensé al comienzo lo mismo tengo no mas  5 valores y cuando ejecuto el método le mando un valor entero que es 0 debería comenzar desde cero y dos pasos hacia adelante y no funciona.

Comment: Lo gracioso es que si coloco  los limites con valores enteros ósea del 1 al 2 si funciona pero colocando un parámetro no.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar la estructura de tu tabla y cómo mandas el parámetro para hacer la consulta.

Comment: abajo en mi código esta el método donde envió el valor del parámetro